# Upload Image directly to bucket on s3 amazon issue

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, multer

I am a newbie on Amazon s3. I am facing the issue regarding uploading the image directly from frontend to amazon s3 bucket.

I also viewed many tutorials but there is no proper explanation of upload image directly to s3. They teach us how to upload image through local computer to s3.

I implemented the code but not able to identified that how I can upload image without saving to my local machine.

Here is the code which I implemented but not luck to achieve it:

```
s3ImageUpload: (req, res) => {
        var fs = require('fs');
        var multer = require('multer');
        var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
        var path = require('path');

        var awsCredFile = path.join(__dirname, '.', 'key.json');

        console.log('awsCredFile is');
        console.log(awsCredFile);

        AWS.config.loadFromPath(awsCredFile);

        var s3 = new AWS.S3();

        var photoBucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'testbucket'}});

        var sampleFile = {
            //"_id" : 345345,
            //"fieldname" : "uploads[]",
            //"originalname" : "female.JPG",
            //"encoding" : "base64",
            //"mimetype" : "image/jpeg",
            "destination" : "./public/images",
            "filename" : "female.jpeg",
            "path" : "/images/female.jpeg",
            //"size" : 251556,
            //"user" : "579fbe61adac4a8a73b6f508"
        };

        var filePathToSend = path.join(__dirname, '../public', sampleFile.path);


        function uploadToS3(filepath, destFileName, callback) {
            photoBucket
                .upload({
                    ACL: 'public-read',
                    Body: fs.createReadStream(filepath),
                    Key: destFileName.toString(),
                    ContentType: 'image/png'
                })
                // http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3/ManagedUpload.html#httpUploadProgress-event
                .on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt) { console.log(evt); })
                // http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3/ManagedUpload.html#send-property
                .send(callback);
        }

        multer({limits: {fileSize:10*1024*1024}});

        console.log('filePathToSend is ');
        console.log(filePathToSend);

        uploadToS3(filePathToSend, sampleFile.filename, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                return res.status(500).send('failed to upload to s3').end();
            }
            res.status(200)
                .send('File uploaded to S3: '
                    + data.Location.replace(/</g, '&lt;')
                    + '<br/><img src="' + data.Location.replace(/"/g, '&quot;') + '"/>')
                .end();
        });

        console.log('uploading now...');
    }
```

Comment: What errors occur when using your code?

Answer (score 0):

Pre-signed URLs could be a good solution for you.

On your backend, you can sign an URL using the AWS SDK. Then you just have to send this URL back to the client. Finally, the client can upload to file using this URL.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html